# Scala: Reading HDFS file as Stream

Tags: scala

I would like to read an HDFS File in scala. This is a text file and wanted to insert a field default value in each line. How do I read the hdfs file as stream line by line?

I got this code:

```
val hdfs = FileSystem.get(new URI("hdfs://df:port/"), new Configuration()) 
val path = new Path("/dir/fileNm")
val stream = hdfs.open(path)
Stream.cons(stream.read, Stream.continually( stream.read))
```

But this read byte by byte. The readLine() is deprecated. How to read a line?
I am using scala version - 2.11.8

Thanks,
Revathy.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `scala.io.Source`:

```
val source = Source.fromInputStream(stream)
source.getLines() // Iterator[String]
```

Comment: The file is an hdfs file

Comment: Yes, I know. Here, `stream` is the byte InputStream from the hdfs file. These two lines in my answer would come after the first three in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you shuld do something similar to this:

```
def readLines = Stream.cons(stream.readLine, Stream.continually( stream.readLine))

readLines.takeWhile(_ != null).foreach(line => println(line))
```

Comment: In stream.readLine, readLine is showing as deprecated. I tried the below:
 val inFile = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream))
def readLines = Stream.cons(inFile.readLine(), Stream.continually(inFile.readLine()))
readLines.takeWhile(_ != null).foreach(line => println(line))

Is this efficient way of coding, as the file is around 1 Tb.

Comment: Do you think the above code is right way to read file functionally in scala?

Answer (score 0):

Pipe the contents to another function that will delineate by new line character then just use that line stream as you normally would.  Sometimes you have to do the work yourself.

Comment: I code as below:

val inFile = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream))
def readLines = Stream.cons(inFile.readLine(), Stream.continually(inFile.readLine()))
readLines.takeWhile(_ != null).foreach(line => println(line))

Is it efficient way of reading 1 TB size file?